# Home-network wifi issue with Macbook Pro

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, mac, macbook-pro

I'm using a Macbook Pro and having problems with the wifi network at home. Every 20-30 minutes, I am unable to connect to the internet although I can login into 192.168.0.1. If I turn the wifi (on the Macbook) off and on, I can access to the internet again.

The strange thing is that this doesn't happen to other devices at home; and it doesn't happen if I use my Macbook in other places (e.g. at work).

So what are possible causes? How can I troubleshoot this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Home wireless router has the latest firmware?

Comment: See signal strength, if the signal is low sometimes the devices cut connectivity, when you turn off an on you forced it to reconnect

Comment: I'm inferring a lot here, but you say you can't access the Internet.  I assume, you're trying to access fully qualified domain names, like www.google.com, as opposed to accessing the non-routeable IP address 192.168.0.1.  OS X has been notorious for DNS problems for the last couple of releases.  Cycling WiFi seems to restart mDNSResponder or discoveryd, depending on your flavor of OS X.

Comment: @Dan Yes, the firmware is latest. It is automatically updated as the router is modem/router combo.

Comment: @MMB I think it has something to do with DHCP lease between the router and the Macbook. If I renew DHCP lease, the connection is normal again. What's strange is that this phenomenon only happens between my Macbook and the home network. I've also increased the lease time to almost unlimited but the lease still expires every half hour or so.

Comment: @Fabian Renewing the lease also resets OS X DNS, which many, many people have complained about.  One work around is to hard code a DNS server entry within your network config, instead of relying on the router to provide it.  Try adding Google's public DNS 8.8.8.8 to your network config and see if you're still losing access to Internet sites.